# In WCF - In the "Faulted" Event - How Do I Get The Exception Details?

Tags: wcf, exception

I have a WCF server and I'm tapping into the "Faulted" event which stupidly only gives me "object sender, EventArgs e". How can I get the current 'Exception' object in that event?

Or, if there is some sort of global system way, like Environment.GetCurrentException(), that would be awesome, but I can't find it.

EDIT: To help explain what I'm hoping for... in ASP.NET, you can do "Server.GetLastError()"... Is there such a thing, or anthing even remotely close in WCF? - OperationContext.Current.GetLastError() would be cool :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, after some more googling with the right keywords, I've found my answer: http://www.steverb.com/post/Useful-WCF-Behaviors-IErrorHandler

Comment: I'm glad the article was helpful. If you have any questions or issues with implementing it let me know. And yes, I joined SO and accumulated rep points just so I could make this comment.

Comment: Even though this answer is 8 years old, could you please post the relevant part of the linked website in the answer here? If this was a new answer, it would get flagged as "link only".