# WCF faulted - what kind of fault?

Tags: wcf

I am using MSMQ and WCF. Now, the MSMQ could become offline or there could be some communication errors between WCF and the destination. 
I know I can subscribe to the Faulted event on the serviceHost and when the MSMQ goes down/offline, I do get that event raised - great. 
However, how is it possible to know the type of fault that has occured? I need to be sure that it is a communication error of some kind and if so, I want to reconnect after a period of time and keep trying until a "magic number" has been reached.

There is no exception being thrown from the service. It's just when MSMQ goes offline, the WCF service does get faulted but need to know the type of fault.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In WCF - In the "Faulted" Event - How Do I Get The Exception Details?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381345/in-wcf-in-the-faulted-event-how-do-i-get-the-exception-details)

Comment: not quite Christian, but thanks. This is for MSMQ but I did see that IErrorHandler documentation on MSDN before but that is for server side, not client side.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the exception details, as Christian K suggests, you're looking for but rather why a WCF service/client doesn't receive other communication exceptions then the reason is the netMsmqBinding is implements a "fire & forget" pattern.

The WCF service is completely disconnected from the client by the MSMQ plumbing, it only listens for messages on the MSMQ target queue. Service operations with the netMsmqBinding must be configured to be one way (return void) because once the WCF client has successfully placed a message in the MSMQ outgoing queue, its work is complete. The assumption is that MSMQ provides *guaranteed* delivery of the message to the WCF service. MSMQ 4.0 will handle the concern you have about "reconnect" and "magic number retries".

Comment: Thanks. I am using MSMQIntegratedBinding, not that it makes much difference. I understand the fire and forget. But I do know that the service CAN become faulted when the MSMQ on the destination is offline (subscribed to the OnFaulted event of the serviceHost class). So I know its faulted but I need to know the type of exception or reason on why its faulted, so I can do my own internal retry of trying to reconnect to that Clustered MSMQ which went offline otherwise the service will NOT be able to receive those messages from the MSMQ queue unless you restart it manually.

Comment: Clustered MSMQ can be finicky. My client uses it but I wasn't involved in setting it up. From our experience, once a message is accepted by MSMQ and placed in the outgoing queue of originating client machine, it is never "lost". We have had issues in development when some servers are brought down periodically and the default time-to-live period ran out so the messages where moved to the System deadletter queue on the client machine. I don't quite understand the rationale for wanting the re-try/re-connect need though.

Comment: it is because in a clustered environment, if you take down one of the nodes, the clusteredMSMQ propogates to the other node and this disconnects the WCF client (becomes faulted). therefore the connected clients lose the connection and wont receive messages but instead the msgs get placed in the queue building up and up and up until you restart the WCF app. Thats why I wanna know when the app gets faulted and to know what KIND of fault it is

Comment: In that situation, I'd create a "heart beat listener" process to be triggered whenever a fault occurs to assess the WCF client condition or possibly based on the quantity of messages in the queue and restart the client if needed. Other than the Christian's suggestion, I don't know of another way to handle that.

Comment: Thanks. another related problem is im creating a new WCF MSMQ. Now a sample I followed on MSDN works just fine but when I Create my own - it does not. I always get a faulted error but I do not know what that fault is. its frustrating trying to find out what faulted. This is simply when the host has opened the connection then I get a fault.

Comment: I'd check permissions on your queues for the account the WCF client/service are running under. If they aren't allowed to access the queue I seem to remember the exceptions this caused seemed confusing.

Comment: no go. I can send messages fine to the queue. but the WCF service that listens doesnt get invoked but faults. no exceptions

Comment: interesting. if I point the WCF host to another MSMQ (the one from the MSDN demo) - its fine. no faults... but obviously the contract does not match the messages in the queue so nothing will be processed. hmmmm

Comment: update: even if I read a string from the queue results in this new service being faulted.

Comment: ok so when I send a string to the MSMQ, it sends fine but then the WCF service faults when it is getting it from the queue I guess.